# Simple and lightweight .eml html renderer on linux?

Tags: email, thunderbird, mutt, evolution, notmuch

I'm testing various email utilities (neomutt, notmuch, mu) and productivity gains they offer are great, but being CLI tools none of them allow you to view rendered html email messages (e.g. .eml files) out of the box, so I'm looking for an external, lightweight tool that can be hooked instead.

There are larger projects like thunderbird or evolution that can be used for that, but perhaps there are other projects that can also quickly render fonts, display images in email messages without requiring 200MB+ on disk or run javascript?

I've tried w3m, but images were flickering a lot depending on terminal and rendered layouts differs from most GUI clients.

Answer (score 1):

[astroid](https://github.com/astroidmail/astroid) is an interesting project that fits the above description pretty well. It requires you to set up [notmuch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Notmuch) first, but then provides fast and lightweight html rendering of messages (opens instantaneously). It also features small install size (on my machine it was only 3.56MB - I've had GTK and Qt already installed though) and configurable vim keybindings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1192656)

Comment: @RohitGupta thanks, I've updated the answer

Comment: Now it wont get deleted and it got upvoted